# Favicon not showing in search results even with Googles Guidelines

Tags: html, google-search, favicon

I followed the guidelines on Favicon at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858?hl=en.

However it has been some time and mt favicon has not been indexed  There are some threads on here but none showed any difinitive resolution.

I had my favicon as an .ico but i changed it to a .png recently.  I also have it set as 48x48 as per googles guidelines.

Any help is apprieciated.

Website is http://veganthingsworld.com

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="Images/favicon.png">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check when google has last crawled you site, otherwise submit it again.

Comment: Did you finally solved it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**On site**

Hints to look at:

- Use the Google Favicon Snatcher to check your favicon as seen by Google. Yours seems okay: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=veganthingsworld.com
- Check your Google Search Console: Google displays your favicon in its interface, and the Search Console seems to be quicker than the search engine.

**Off site**

Of course, this feature completely depends on Google. It takes at least a few days or even weeks for Google to show your favicon in its results pages. The delay seems to depend on the popularity of your site.

The fact that Google crawled your site does not mean that your favicon will be displayed in the next few hours/days. If you are analyzing your HTTP logs, look for `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, comme Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 Google Favicon` (the user agent is different from the regular search engine user agent).

Comment: I just noticed its added to www.veganthingsworld.com but not the https://veganthingsworld.com. A bit strange.

Comment: I've followed google's guidelines, the google favicon snatcher shows my favicon, it's shown in Google Search Console too... but it doesn't show up in google search results for more than one month... Do you have any other clue about this?

Comment: @zapico When I experimented with favicon in Google SERP, I noticed it could take weeks for Google to reflect changes for a site with nearly no traffic (bad point) but known by Google for years (good point). So even if a month sounds like forever, my advice here is to be patient and keep the faith :)

Comment: Thanks for your words @philippe_b but this site has a lot of traffic and almost 2 months now and still no changes and zero support from google.

Comment: @zapico I admit that's a long time... Do you still face the issue? When you said the site receives traffic, did you mean traffic *from Google*? Did you have the opportunity to look for the Google favicon user agent in your logs (see my answer above for the exact name)?

Comment: I still face it and it seems it's going to be forever :(. Yes, we receive traffic from google daily, I'll check if we receive traffic from that bot.