# How can I change the icon that shows in Google Search results?

Tags: html, google-chrome, devops, google-search

As it's shown in the picture below is my new website with its old icon showing there and I want to change that icon to a new one but I do not know how.

[image]

And the configuration of the favicon in my HTML code is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137118/favicon-not-showing-in-search-results-even-with-googles-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indexing the site after changing the favicon. It might take few days to update on the Google Search Results.